# Differences between "industrial" and "home" usb hubs?

Tags: usb, hub, usb-hub

I suspect that some of my USB issues are related to the hub that I am using, and I did some research on "industrial" USB hubs.  So far, it looks like these hubs offer the following major differences:

- ESD protection
- Surge protection
- Metal housing
- Wider operational temperature range
- Has a vibration/shock spec
- Better USB connectors
- Terminal block for power connection (sometimes)

But in the absence of high vibration, crazy temps, and electrical surges, is there really any other difference?  In other words, do they use "special" USB chips that will inherently make USB comms more reliable than typical home USB hubs like those from D-Link or ioGear?  What about the sort of testing processes that are used when manufacturing industrial grade hubs?

Comment: There is no difference between "industrial" and "home" USB hubs then perhaps design of the product itself.  ESD protection would exist in all lines.  "Better USB connection" is marketing speak for "more expensive stuff that does exactly the samething as the cheaper stuff".  USB 2 is USB 2 END OF STORY.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it, the industrial line is likely just protected from hazardous environments a bit better.

I think you'll find that a lot of industrial computing equipment isn't that different from the home spec apart from environmental protection.